# Paypal's new ssl requirements

Tags: ssl, paypal, woocommerce

this year paypal have been informing site owners they need ssl with HTTPS requirement for IPN Postback and SHA-256  etc

I have a website which uses woocommerce, I pass my checkout basket to paypal to process the payment and get a success or fail back to add an order onto my site.

Do I need all this SSL etc on my site even though im using a cart which doesn't process payments itself it hands data to paypal to process?

or can I carry on with no ssl

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need SSL on your site.  In fact, [the notice regarding IPN](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1916&expand=true&locale=en_US) explicitly says "there is no requirement for HTTPS on the outbound IPN call from PayPal to the merchant's IPN listener".

The changes that are coming are in regards to PayPal's setup.  Since part of the process in receiving an IPN is posting it back to PayPal for verification, you need to make sure that your system will still be able to communicate back to PayPal after the changes are done.  Since WooCommerce runs on PHP and cURL, this will mean making sure that the underlying SSL libraries are up-to-date:

- Most servers use OpenSSL.  If this is the case, you need to make sure that you're using at least version 1.0.1.
- Some Linux distros (centOS in particular) use NSS instead of OpenSSL.  If this is the case, you'll need to make sure that you're using version 3.15.1 or better.
- If you're unfortunate enough to have your store hosted on a server running OS X, you'll need to make sure that the server is running OS X 10.8 or better.

Since almost all PHP and cURL setups get all of their SSL/TLS capabilities from one of these libraries, this should be all most people need to do.